# Pandas creates new excel sheet when trying to append to existing sheet

Tags: python, pandas

I have the code where I want to read data from the current sheet, store it in  df_old, append the current data to it using `df = df_old.append(df)` and then replace the data in the sheet with this new dataframe. However, what it does instead is create a new sheet with the exact same name where it publishes this new dataframe. I tried adding `if_sheet_exists="replace"` as an argument to ExcelWriter but this did not change anything. How can I force it to overwrite the data in the sheet with the current name?

```
df_old = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\Digitalisation\mat_flow\reblend_v2.xlsx',sheet_name = ft_tags_final[i][j])
df = df_old.append(df)
        
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\Digitalisation\mat_flow\reblend_v2.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name = ft_tags_final[i][j])
```

Comment: What happens if you use `write` mode instead of `append`? Change it to `mode="w"`?

Comment: Just tried it @DavidDavó but it raised an error. I have around 30 sheets, and the above code is looped 30 times but after the first iteration it seems to wipe all the sheets and I get an error saying "worksheet XXXX not found". Opened the excel file to see only the first sheet there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i solved it with using `write` instead of `append`. Also i used `openpyxl` instead of `xlsxwriter`

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('Wallet.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Wallet.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
#^THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT LINES BECAUSE IT GIVES PANDAS THE SHEET

Data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Main', header=None, index=False, startcol=number,startrow=counter)
```